# AWS S3 - Generate presigned URL using REST API

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to generate a presigned URL for an S3 object using the AWS REST API rather than the SDKs?  I can't find the topic for this in the AWS REST API documentation.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to minimize the size of code imported. I don't believe there is an API request you can make for this. You could extract the signing code from the AWS SDK source (not sure how simple this would be) or write your own signing code using a combination of the SDK source and AWS's documentation. Or you could write a trivial Lambda function that maps an S3 key to a pre-signed URL and then have your client invoke the Lambda (or make an API call vi API Gateway).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You won't find a REST endpoint for generating a presigned URL because that URL is generated entirely client-side. :) The python code used to generate those URLs can be found in the `generate_presigned_url` method of the `signers.py` in the [botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore) library.

You can verify the client-sidedness of the presigned-url generation in two ways:

1. Grab a network traffic analyzer and compare the traffic of a bucket-list operation and a generate-presigned-url operation
2. Generate a presigned-url for a non-existent bucket using invalid credentials and marvel as a totally non-fucntional presigned url is still happily generated for you

Comment: Worth mentioning, the algorithm for creating your own pre-signed URLs is also documented: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

Comment: Many thanks Michael, I didn't spot the algorithm was documented!

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with the first answer.

You can generate Pre-SignedURL with lambda functions connected to your POST request.  Go to Boto3 library and search Pre-signed URL and you can get the code.   When a bucket and key is send back to the API Gateway,  A Pre-SignedURL is generated. You can also generate Binary Images.

Comment: Minor correction. Search for "presigned urls" to return results in Boto3 lib docs.